# Template specialisation on substitution failure

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this function:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T c) {
    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
}
```

You see that it will not compile for types which does not have an `operator<<`  overload.
Now I want to write a function that acts like a fallback for this case.

```
/*Fallback*/
template<>
void f(T c) {
    std::cout<<"Not Printing"<<std::endl;
}
```

How must this function be defined to do the job?

Comment: Unless you can modify the the first overload, you don't have any way to add a fallback mechanism. The substitution in SFINAE happens way before the body is instantiated.

Comment: Thats not a problem, I can modify the first one too.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: C++20 concept should allow that (more specialized overload for `requires (!Stremable<T>`)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Copy and Paste error

Comment: @Jarod42 - Not a particularly sound practice if more than one extra overload is involved though. Subsumption is defined with the assumption that "fallbacks" are less specialized. Not that we *can't* make it work... it will just be less pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

You have **several options** of doing this. Arguably the most elegant way is to define your [own **type trait** (similar to the ones in `type_traits`)](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/12/02/your-own-type-predicate/).

Let's define a **`is_streamable` type trait**. It takes two template arguments: `S` is the data type of the file stream (e.g. `std::ostream` or `std::fstream` or any other type that defines a custom streaming operator that is compatible with `T`) and secondly the data type of the object to be streamed into this file stream `T`:

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename = void>
struct is_streamable : std::false_type {
};

template<typename S, typename T>
struct is_streamable<S, T, decltype(std::declval<S&>() << std::declval<T&>(), void())> : std::true_type {
};
```

So far this type trait compiles with C++11 and onwards. For C++14 and later we can create a convenient **alias** for it similar to other type traits in C++17:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
static constexpr is_streamable_v = is_streamable<S,T>::value;
```

This type trait will now be the basis for the next step which will make use of `SFINAE` (C++11 onwards), `constexpr if` (C++17 onwards) or `concepts` (C++20).

- In **C++11** you could achieve this with either by putting the different implementations into partial specialisations of the same struct and call it with a helper function:

  ```
  class f_imp {
  };

  template <typename T>
  class f_imp<T,true> {
    public:
      static constexpr void imp(T c) {
        std::cout << "streamable: " << c << std::endl;
      }
  };

  template <typename T>
  class f_imp<T,false> {
    public:
      static constexpr void imp(T c) {
        std::cout << "not streamable" << std::endl;
      }
  };

  template <typename T>
  void f(T c) {
    return f_imp<T,is_streamable<std::ostream,T>::value>::imp(c);
  }
  ```

  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ieMifFqJN9VOTUK4)

  Alternatively you could apply `SFINAE` either by adding a second input parameter or applying it to the return type:

  ```
  template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<is_streamable<std::ostream,T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  void f(T t) {
    std::cout << "streamable" << std::endl;
  }

  template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!is_streamable<std::ostream,T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  void f(T t) {
    std::cout << "not streamable" << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c0O1aiczM40kS59l)
- In **C++17** you can actually use a **`constexpr if`** to avoid adding a second template argument and overloading of the function altogether. You can insert all the code inside the function and use `if constexpr` in combination with `std::is_same_v` and our `is_streamable_v` to decide at compile time which branch of our code each template type should take. This is in particular convenient if adding two specialisations would result in duplicate code but it might be harder to read.

  ```
  template<typename T>
  void f(T c) {
    if constexpr (is_streamable_v<std::ostream,T>) {
      std::cout << "streamable:" << c << std::endl;
    } else {
      // Fallback
      std::cerr << "not streamable" << std::endl;
    }
    return;
  }
  ```

  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HIItVqYeb0M6Y6lB)
- Finally in **C++20** you could use this type trait to define a **concepts** such as `streamable` and `not_streamable`:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  concept streamable = is_streamable_v<std::ostream,T>;

  template <typename T>
  concept not_streamable = !streamable<T>;
  ```

  Then you can go on to apply them to your two overloads of the functions

  ```
  template <streamable T>
  void f(T c) {
    std::cout << "streamable: " << c << std::endl;
  }

  template <not_streamable T>
  void f(T c) {
    std::cout << "not streamable" << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HM6IcmBK7Yqzq5Cf)

Be aware that you will have to also **apply the same logic to any custom streaming operator of a templated class**, e.g. of a templated vector. Instead of declaring the operator for any template parameter `typename T` you would have to only declare it for streamable element types only. In C++20 for example with said `streamable` concept:

```
template <streamable T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& vec) {
  for (auto const& v: vec) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  return os;
}
```

Otherwise - as the template argument to the `is_streamable` operator is `std::vector<T>` as a whole - the compiler sees the `operator <<` for `std::vector<T>` without checking if it would result in a compilation error for an unstreamable type `T` which does not define the `operator <<` itself.

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/79OSZlpAu8t1Hvmn)

Answer (score 1):

Pre-C++20

To have these overloads work in a fallback way, we can start by defining a trait that detects the validity of the expression involving `operator <<`

```
namespace detail {
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct streamable : std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct streamable<T, decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T&>(), void())> : std::true_type {};
}
```

It's just your typical use of the detection idiom with as little extra library support as possible. Depending on the standard you are building against, this may be written in other ways (for instance `std::void_t` can be used, if available).

Now, the two overloads can be specified rather simply:

```
template<typename T>
auto f(T c) -> std::enable_if_t<detail::streamable<T>::value, void> {
    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
auto f(T c) -> std::enable_if_t<!detail::streamable<T>::value, void> {
    /// other code
}
```

---

Post C++20, concepts and constraints make it a whole lot easier. It can even be written ad-hoc:

```
template<typename T>
requires requires(std::ostream& os, T& c) { os << c; }
void f(T c) {
    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T> // No extra step, subsumed by the above when possible
void f(T c) {
    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) (C++20), we can achieve this like so:

```
template<typename T>
concept Streamable = requires(T t){std::declval<std::ostream&>() << t; };

template<Streamable T>
void f(T c) { std::cout << c << std::endl; }

/*Fallback*/
template<typename T>
void f(T c) { std::cout << "fallback" < <std::endl; }
```

### [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cxGWddGKq)

---

Test:

```
struct Foo{};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    f(foo); // prints "fallback"

    int a = 42;
    f(a); // prints "42"
}
```

---

If you want to make doubly sure that your fallback will only happen if your type is not `Streamable`, you can constrain it, too:

```
template<typename T> requires (!Streamable<T>)
void f(T c) { /*...*/ }
```