# Check if << operator is applicable in overriding template context

Tags: c++11, templates, operator-overloading, overriding, iostream

I have made a `AnyType` class which is similar to std::any in C++14. I would like to override the `<<` operator to easily print the content of the stored variable:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const AnyType& v ) {
  if( v._varPtr_ != nullptr ) v._varPtr_->writeToStream(o);
  return o;
}
```

And the `writeToStream()` is an overrided function defined in a `PlaceHolder` class which is holding the actual typed variable. It is defined as:

```cpp
void writeToStream(std::ostream& o) const override { o << _variable_; }
```

My problem is when I define a `AnyType` object which is holding a variable type with no `operator<<` overrided, the compiler is throwing an (expected) error while unfolding a defined template class:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const TGraph')
    void writeToStream(std::ostream& o) const override { o << _variable_; }
                                                         ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is a minimal example:

```cpp
struct PlaceHolder{
  virtual ~PlaceHolder() = default;
  virtual void writeToStream(std::ostream& o) const = 0;
};

template<typename VariableType> struct VariableHolder: public PlaceHolder{
  explicit VariableHolder(VariableType value_) : _variable_(std::move(value_)){  }
  void writeToStream(std::ostream& o) const override { o << _variable_; }

  VariableType _variable_;
};

class AnyType{
public:
  AnyType(){}
  template<typename ValueType> inline void setValue(const ValueType& value_){ 
    _varPtr_ = std::shared_ptr<VariableHolder<ValueType>>(new VariableHolder<ValueType>(value_)); 
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const AnyType& v ) {
    if( v._varPtr_ != nullptr ) v._varPtr_->writeToStream(o);
    return o;
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<PlaceHolder> _varPtr_{nullptr};
};

int main(){

  AnyType a;
  a.setValue(int(14));
  std::cout << a << std::endl; // this will work

  // If the following line is uncommented, the compiler will throw an error
  // a.setValue(TGraph()); // this is a CERN's ROOT class
  

}
```

So my question is: **Is there any way to make the compiler check if it is possible to override `<<` before having it explicilty** ? This way I could let the `writeToStream` method to be defined as default: `= 0`.

May be there is another workarround. Typically this problem does not appear with `std::any`. Does anyone knows how it is implemented in the std library?

Cheers :)

Comment: You mean you are looking for a way to check if `__variable__` can be streamed into an `std::ostream`? Where is `__variable__` defined? Could you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes exactly!
`_variable_` is defined under the `PlaceHolder` struct. I will try to make a minimal example

Comment: Hmmmm, I see but you want to set the data type of `_varPtr_` at runtime. This disqualifies the use of templates and SFINAE. You could do it with templates if `AnyType` would be a template class with a fixed `ValueType`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, I saw your solution. Already had noted down the almost identical solution.

Comment: I see, but std::any manage to do the job without explicitly being defined as a template. Is there some tricks with `std::enable_if` I could use?

Comment: I came up with a solution based on a proprietary type-trait and `std::enable_if` that enables and disables the stream inside the `writeToStream` function of the `VariableHolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, generally speaking this is possible but only if your class `AnyType` would be a template class. In this case you could disable the `operator<<` directly with [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). As in your case which precise variable type is held by the shared pointer inside `AnyType` is decided on runtime you can't simply disable it with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). What you can do though is **use a type-trait inside the virtual method to decide if the stream should be modified or not** depending on the template parameter `VariableType` of `VariableHolder`:

Just define a [**type-trait**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) [`is_streamable` as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705635/9938686)

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename = void>
struct is_streamable : std::false_type {
};

template<typename S, typename T>
struct is_streamable<S, T, decltype(std::declval<S&>() << std::declval<T&>(), void())> : std::true_type {
};
```

where `S` corresponds to the stream (e.g. `std::ostream`) and `T` to the data type to be checked to be streamable into `S`.

Then use it to disable it inside the `VariableHolder::writeToStream` to decide whether the stream should be modified or not. With **C++17** you could use [**`if constexpr`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```
template<typename VariableType>
struct VariableHolder: public PlaceHolder {
  explicit VariableHolder(VariableType value_)
    : _variable_(std::move(value_)) {
    return;
  }
  void writeToStream(std::ostream& o) const override {
    // Only for streamable variable types
    if constexpr (is_streamable<std::ostream,VariableType>::value) {
      o << _variable_;
    }
    return;
  }
  VariableType _variable_;
};
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IOOFAOqy2PWlUqgs)

In **C++11** (as requested) and C++14 it is a bit more complicated and you will have to use a **helper struct** and **partially specialise** it for `true` (streamable types) and `false` (non-streamable types) and then call it with our previously introduced type-trait `is_streamable` as follows:

```
template <typename T, bool>
class helper {
};

// Partial specialisation for streamable variable types
template <typename T>
class helper<T,true> {
  public:
    static void imp(std::ostream& os, T const& t) {
      // Stream variable t to stream os
      os << t;
      return;
    }
 };

 // Partial specialisation for non-streamable variable types
 template <typename T>
 class helper<T,false> {
   public:
     static void imp(std::ostream&, T const&) {
       // Leave stream os unmodified
       return;
     }
 };

 template<typename VariableType>
 struct VariableHolder: public PlaceHolder {
   explicit VariableHolder(VariableType value_)
     : _variable_(std::move(value_)) {
     return;
   }
   void writeToStream(std::ostream& o) const override {
     // Call suiting helper function depending on template parameter
     helper<VariableType, is_streamable<std::ostream,VariableType>::value>::imp(o, _variable_);
     return;
   }
   VariableType _variable_;
 };
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0zZZCQVCko8bAasN)

Comment: Nice! It's nearly working in my program but I have still a problem: `Constexpr function's return type 'void' is not a literal type` I can change the return type to bool for example but then the compiler throws a warning saying the use of `os << ` is C++14. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: @nadrino Probably you should remove the `constexpr`. It is not necessary. I deleted it from my solution. Let me know if that works for you or if the error still persists.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works by removing the `constexpr` ! :D

Comment: @nadrino You are welcome! Glad I could help. I am not sure if it used to be like this in C++11 (have been working with C++17 mainly now for some time) or if it is just a compiler bug of an older GCC compiler.